# Have to test lambda several times before it works

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a lambda function that I am playing around with. It inserts very basic information into a DynamoDB table. Here is the code:

```
'use strict';
const alexaSkillKit = require('alexa-skill-kit');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

function binDaySkill(event, context, callback) {
    alexaSkillKit(event, context, (message) => {

        let params = {
            Item:      {
                user_id:       '123',
                some_data: 'some data here'
            },
            TableName: 'my_table'
        };

        let documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

        documentClient.put(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                callback("Error", err);
            } else {
                callback(null, data);
            }
        });

    });
}
```

The issue I am having is that it only *sometimes* saves the data in the DB. I have to click test 5-10 times before it does anything.

Can anyone help with what might be causing this?

Comment: have you checked CloudWatch for possible errors?

Comment: Can you please share your test event payload data. Are you using hard-coded value for user_id & some_data (user_id:'123', some_data: 'some data here') in your snippet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because `alexa-skill-kit` takes care of the callback for you.

See the [documentation](https://github.com/stojanovic/alexa-skill-kit#api-reference). By passing in the `context` object you allow the wrapping handler (`alexaSkillKit(...)`) to manage decoding and encoding the returned objects and payload. The handler `alexSkillKit` callback function just expects you to *return* a value.

For your code sample you could do the following:

```
'use strict';
const alexaSkillKit = require('alexa-skill-kit');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

function binDaySkill(event, context, callback) {
  alexaSkillKit(event, context, (message) => {
    let params = {
      Item: {
        user_id: '123',
        some_data: 'some data here'
      },
      TableName: 'my_table'
    };

    let documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    return documentClient.put(params).promise()
      .then((data) => {
        // stuff with the data!
        return data;
      }).catch((err) => {
        // stuff with the error
        throw err;
      });  
  });
}
```

*n.b. The reason it worked after a few invocations is that lambda re-uses the environments each invocation executes in. It does this by effectively "freezing" the state of the environment and thawing it when it's needed again. This is the basis of a lot of optimisations people make; and it meant that you would sometimes thaw an environment that was midway through calling back when it was frozen by the alexaSkillKit returning first.*

Comment: Thank you for providing a working solution AND explaining it!